# GGplot legend square - why doesn't it fill entirely?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a graph I've plotted and used squares in my legend but for some reason it seems to have a line running through it - not sure why?

[image]

This is the code I used to get this:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15))
```

I'd like it to be a solid-filled square

Comment: You presumably have a geom_text layer that needs a `geom_text(show.legend = FALSE)`